# Porting some functions to arnold 6

Tags: c++, 3d, port, rendering, maya

Im currently porting a project written with arnold 4 sdk to arnold 6 sdk

The problems i have is that i cant find some of the arnold 4 functions, the functions are:

[`AiEvaluateLightSample`](https://trac.solidangle.com/arnoldpedia/chrome/site/Arnold-4.1.3.3/doc/api/group__ai__shader__brdf.html#ga6a57fea499da6740bbbf00f6a669673c)

`AiShaderGlobalsApplyOpacity`

Answer (score 0):

AiShaderGlobalsApplyOpacity --> AiShaderGlobalsStochasticOpacity()

Are you sure you want to do your own lightloop instead of leaving it to Arnold? The advantage of the closures is that you do not have to care about light samples any more and give Arnold the full control to optimize sampling. So if you really want to do it, have a look at the Arnold_5_Porting_Guide.pdf which contains most of the needed info.